# How to count non-ASCII characters with Git commit-msg hook on Windows?

Tags: git, githooks, tortoisegit

I work with Git on Windows via TortoiseGit and currently I'm trying to use [this commit-msg hook](https://gist.github.com/agnivade/67b42d664ece2d4210c7) to check length of commit messages' lines.

All is fine when i write messages exclusively with ASCII characters. But when I write a message in Russian, a character counter produces a result two times greater than actual length. It looks like the counter uses a default Windows encoding or something like that while a message is being saved as UTF-8 file.

Some highlights:

- `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` has UTF-8 encoding;
- `echo $line` in my hook displays non-ASCII characters correctly;
- `${#line}` returns a value equal to `actual_length * 2`;
- I tried different ways of iterating over characters in a line and each time iterator treated each byte as a separate character.

*Update 1*: I want to achieve my goal without adding environmental dependencies (that is, without installation of additional interpreters like Python).

Answer (score 1):

Don't count bytes — count characters. I.e., convert (decode) input from bytes to characters in your programming language. Russian characters encoded in UTF-8 take 2 bytes. Example (in Python):

```
$ python

>>> len('тест')
8

>>> len(u'тест')
4

>>> len('тест'.decode('utf-8'))
4
```

Comment: I don't want to use Python, I want to modify the shell script from the link I provided. I thought it is clear from the question, it looks like I need to clarify it

Comment: And of course I wouldn't ask this question if I knew how to count characters in an encoding-aware manner in Git shell :)

Comment: I didn't say "Use Python" — Python was only an example. What I say is basically "Use a real programming language". If you prefer Java — let it be Java. I doubt bash is suitable for the task of unicode *character* manipulation (versus bytes).

Answer (score 0):

For now, `echo $line | iconv --from-code UTF-8 --to-code cp866` did the trick.

It covers my use case (only Cyrillic or Basic Latin characters are expected in messages) but lacks generality. I hope someone knows a cleaner solution.

Here is my current script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#http://chris.beams.io/posts/git-commit/#seven-rules
cnt=0

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
  cnt=$((cnt+1))
  cp866_line=`echo $line | iconv --from-code UTF-8 --to-code cp866`

  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    length=${#cp866_line}
  else
    length=${#line}
  fi

  if [ $cnt -eq 1 ]; then
    # Checking if subject exceeds 50 characters
    if [ $length -gt 50 ]; then
      echo "Your subject line exceeds 50 characters"
      exit 1
    fi
    i=$(($length-1))
    last_char=${line:$i:1}
    # Subject line must not end with a period
    if [[ $last_char == "." ]]; then
      echo "Your subject line ends with a period"
      exit 1
    fi
  elif [ $cnt -eq 2 ]; then
    # Subject must be followed by a blank line
    if [ $length -ne 0 ]; then
      echo "Your subject line is followed by a non-empty line"
      exit 1
    fi
  else
    # Any line in body must not exceed 72 characters
    if [ $length -gt 72 ]; then
      echo "The line \"$line\" exceeds 72 characters"
      exit 1
    fi
  fi
done < "$1"
```